# How do you make a keyboard app in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am sorry if this question is frequently asked, simple to answer or not defined enough. I'll provide as many details as I can.

Anyway

You've probably heard of the app called Giphy. It's an app via which you can send GIF images to others. When you download the app, you also have an integrated keyboard which you can use instead of the standard keyboard you get with your phone [image: Looks something like this]

I just recently started learning flutter and I wanted to try and make a keyboard of my own. Is there a way to do that in flutter? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create Keyboard input editor app in flutter, because it is very specific to native application. So try to create it natively for both Android and iOS.

Check below links, might help you:

For Android:

- [Create an input method editor (IME)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method)

For iOS:

- [Creating a Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/keyboards_and_input/creating_a_custom_keyboard)
- [Creating a Custom Keyboard In IOS…](https://medium.com/swift-india/creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-ios-a75e7d5cc5ef)